# createJS регистрация нового звука в вызове функции

Tags: javascript, python, html5, python-3.x, websocket

Есть задача, получать на вход текст, преобразовывать его в речь, и записывать в файловую систему аудио файл, для последующего воспроизведения в `HTML`.

Всё хорошо работало, когда я передавал в функцию сгенерированный `filename`, и отдавал на клиент этот `filename`, и при помощи шаблонизатора изменял название файла для воспроизведения. Минусом было лишь то, что со временнем этих файлов нагеренилось достаточное количество, а смысла как такового в них не было. Но так как это был прототип, это работало, а значит не требовало оптимизации.

Тогда я использовал обычную синхронную обработку `request` и возвращал `response` перезагружая страницу.

Сейчас же всё немного изменилось.

Теперь клиент с сервером общается через `Websocket`, `filename` не передаю, а пытаюсь перезаписывать каждый раз, при обращении со стороны клиента.

Вот простая функция:

```
def text_to_speach(text):

    with open(join(dirname(__file__),'resources/text.wav'),
              'wb') as audio_file:
        audio_file.write(
            text_to_speech.synthesize(str(text), accept='audio/wav',
                                      voice="en-US_AllisonVoice"))
```

Вот так регистрирую аудиофайл:

```
createjs.Sound.on("fileload", this.loadHandler, this);
```

Вот функция, по вызову которой воспроизводится файл:

```
function loadHandler(event) {
    createjs.Sound.play("x");
}
```

вот обработчик `onmessage`:

```
socket.onmessage = function(e) {
    createjs.Sound.registerSound("resources/text.wav", "x"); // регистрирую файл
    loadHandler() // вызываю функцию для воспроизведения 
}
```

Вместо классического `<audio></audio>` решил использовать эту [либу](http://createjs.com/), по крайней мере для того, чтобы воспроизводилось на мобильных браузерах.

Проблема заключается в том, что аудиофайл вопроизводится один и тот же, хотя он перезаписывается.
И иногда, что-то происходит не так, и весь процесс становится колом, до тех пор, пока не перезагружу страницу. В логах ничего не вижу, отловить ошибку не получается.

Как сделать так, чтобы проигрывался свежезаписанный файл ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Удалось решить следующим образом:

1. Та же функция, срабатывающая при поступлении данных от сервера, только сейчас я паршу JSON, и вызываю функцию инициализации:

   socket.onmessage = function(e) {
       data = JSON.parse(e.data)
       app.newMessage(data.text)
       initialHandler()
   }
2. Вот 3 функции, в `initialHandler` я вызываю переменную, и вызываю функцию `playHandler`, которая проигрывает файл, если он зарегистрирован, если же нет, то вызывается функция `registerHandler`, в которой регистрируется файл, и после его успешной регистрации снова запускается `playHandler`:

   ```
   function initialHandler(event) {
     Voice = "resources/" + data.filename + ".wav";
     playHandler();
   }
   function registerHandler() {
     createjs.Sound.registerSound(Voice);
     createjs.Sound.on("fileload", playHandler);
   }
   function playHandler() {
     if(createjs.Sound.loadComplete(Voice)) {
       createjs.Sound.play(Voice);
     } else {
       registerHandler()
     }
   }
   ```
3. Функция на python, которая проверяет, существует ли файл в системе, а в остальном, делает то же самое:

Н

```
file_path = join(dirname(__file__),'resources/{}.wav'.format(filename))
if not os.path.exists(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'wb') as audio_file:
        audio_file.write(
            text_to_speech.synthesize(str(text), 
                accept='audio/wav',
                voice="en-US_AllisonVoice")
            )
```

Если кто-то видит, как можно упростить мой `JS` код, то, с радостью приму помощь и внесу правки в ответ.